# How to find the domain of this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

f(x)= $\frac{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1} )}{( \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1} )}\;$

first off $\sqrt{x}$ is defined for:

$$x > 0                   \tag{1}$$

and  $\sqrt{x-1}$ is defined for:

$$x \ge 1                 \tag{2}$$

from $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get domain of $f(x)$ should be $\{x | x\ge 1\}$

We found the domains of elementary functions contained in $f(x)$ and intersected them to find the domain of $f(x)$.

but putting $x = 0$, we get

$$f(0)= -1$$

why this solution was not contained in the above mentioned solution? I always find the domains of composite functions by this way, How can I be sure that some points, like $(0,-1)$ in above problem, are still not included in the solution?

Comment: How did you get $f(0)=-1$?

Comment: @KennyLau $\sqrt{x}$ disappears, so it is $-z/z=-1$.  But this involves complex numbers, because $\sqrt{0-1}=i$.  Krishanu's solution of $x>1$ is correct, although I think it should be $x\geq1$.  The function is only defined when every step in the process works, including $\sqrt{x-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 
$$f(x) = \frac{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1} )}{( \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1} )}$$
The domain of $f$ is:
$$D_f = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : (\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1} \ne 0) \wedge (x \ge 0) \wedge (x-1 \ge 0) \}$$

- Let we consider the first inequality: $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1} \ne 0$
  To make the explanation clearer let we consider to negation:
  $$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x-1} = -\sqrt{x}$$
  Because $(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}): \sqrt{x} \ge 0 \Rightarrow \sqrt{x-1} = -\sqrt{x}$ is not solvable($\sqrt{x-1}$ can not be negative)
  The solution is $\emptyset$, because we considered the negation, so we must negate it again what result $\mathbb{R}$ Let $D_1$ denotes the first solution set, so $D_1 = \mathbb{R}$
- Now let consider the second inequality: $x \ge 0$
  This inequality is already solved. In analogue to the first case let $D_2$ denotes the second solution set, so $D_2 = [0,+\infty[$
- Now let consider the last inequality: $ x-1 \ge 0 $
  $ x-1 \ge 0 \Leftrightarrow x \ge 1 \Leftrightarrow D_3 = [1,+\infty[$
  The whole solution $$D_f= D_1 \cap D_2 \cap D_3$$
  $$\Leftrightarrow D_f= \mathbb{R} \cap [0,+\infty[ \cap [1,+\infty[$$
  $$\Leftrightarrow D_f= [1,+\infty[$$

Comment: The denominator is $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x - 1}$, so we want $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x - 1} \neq 0$.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You wrote $\sqrt{x} \color{red}{-} \sqrt{x - 1} \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you

Comment: In your first bullet point, you meant to say $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x - 1} \neq 0$.  That said, if you first establish that $\sqrt{x} \implies x \geq 0$ and $\sqrt{x - 1} \implies x - 1 \geq 0 \implies x \geq 1$, you obtain $\sqrt{x - 1} = -\sqrt{x}$ has no solution since $-\sqrt{x} \leq -1$ and $\sqrt{x - 1}$ cannot be negative.

Comment: Where does $-\sqrt{x} \leq -1$ come from? Do you mean $-\sqrt{x} \leq 0$?

Comment: Since we require $x  \geq 0$ and $x \geq 1$, we must have $x \geq 1$.  Hence, $-\sqrt{x} \leq -\sqrt{1} = - 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a fraction, and fractions are defined everywhere the denominator is non-zero (which it is). The numerator is defined when $[0,\infty) \cap [1,\infty) = [1,\infty)$, (the square root is defined at $0$), and the denominator is defined for
$$
\{x : \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x-1} \neq 0, \, x\geq 0, x\geq 1\} = [1,\infty)
$$
so the domain is $[1,\infty)$.

By this, we should see that $f(0)$ is not defined.

Comment: I think it is very interesting that Mr. Singh would ask why $0$ is not in the domain since one can argue that $f(0)=-1$. I would be impressed if a student asked this question. And the response that, well, because you must use complex numbers to come to that conclusion seems rather weak to me.

Comment: Assuming that the domain is real, which I do not think is presumptuous, then it is simply just not defined. I suppose I interpreted the question differently.

Answer (score 0):

To me, your observation seems correct. I assume this is a real function. We have

$$f(x) = \frac{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-1} )}{( \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1} )}\ = (\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x-1})^2$$ For $x\geq 1$ this is defined, of course. For $x\leq0$ substitute $x \to -t$ so that we have $$(i\sqrt{t} - i\sqrt{t+1})^2 = -(\sqrt t - \sqrt {t+1})^2$$ $f$ maps values of $x\leq0$ to $\mathbb{R}$ so this is, in fact, in the domain (though since complex numbers are being used in the process, some may disagree with this).

If $x \in (0,1)$, the above argument fails. In particular, we then have $(\sqrt{x} - i\sqrt{1-x})^2$ which has an imaginary component.

We thus conclude that the domain is $\mathbb{R} \setminus (0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Putting $x=0$, we get $$f(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{0}-\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{0}+\sqrt{-1}}$$
So we are getting $\sqrt{-1}$ somewhere in this function which is not real. Therefore $f(0)$ is not defined.

Comment: but $\sqrt{-1}$ cancels out.

Comment: @KrishanuSingh In square roots we should not get any imaginary number if we are working with real numbers. Once we get the imaginary number we should stop and take that function as undefined  at that point.

Comment: @KrishanuSingh In other words when there is something negative in square roots then it loses its meaning. You can google the graph of $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @manshu $x \to \sqrt{x}$ does not map values $x<0$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This function does.